# How to reduce index size of a table in mysql using innodb engine?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, innodb

I am facing a performance issue in mysql due to large index size on my table. Index size has grown to 6GB and my instance is running on 32GB memory. Majority of rows is not required in that table after a few hours and can be removed selectively. But removing them is a time consuming solution and doesn't reduce index size.

Please suggest some solution to manage this index.

Comment: how you know that your index size is 6GB and it is creating problem, innodb_file_per_table is enabled or ot in your setup...may you show your table schema by "show create table your_table;"

Comment: i have checked the size of index by SHOW TABLE STATUS.

Comment: innodb_file_per_table is also enabled

Answer (score 3):

You can optimize your table to rebuild index and get back space if not getting even after deletion-

```
optimize table table_name;
```

But as your table is bulky so it will lock during optimze table and also you are facing issue how can remove old data even you don't need few hours old data. So you can do as per below-

Step1: during night hours or when there is less traffic on your db, first rename your main table and create a new table with same name. Now insert few hours data from old table to new table.

By this you can remove unwanted data and also new table will be optimzed.

Step2: In future to avoid this issue, you can create a stored procedure. Which will will execute in night hours only 1 time per day and either delete till previous day (as per your requirement) data from this table or will move data to any historical table.

Step3: As now your table always keep only sigle day data then you can execute optimize table statement to rebuild and claim space back on this table easily.

Note: delete statement will not rebuild index and will not free space on server. For this you need to do optimize your table. It can be by various ways like by alter statement or by optimize statement etc.

Comment: what if any update request comes-in on old table, during transition phase ? That request will get failed.

Comment: as you are saying that only few hours old data is useful..so first create a same table mytable_new...then insert few hours data from main table to this table....now you just need to rename both tables...which should take hardly second...you can either block all users if this critical for you or you can take risk in late night hours...as per your project criticality....

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove *all* the rows older than X hours, then `PARTITIONing` is the way to go.  `PARTITION BY RANGE` on the hour and use `DROP PARTITION` to remove an old hour and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` to create a new hour.  You should have X+2 partitions.  [More details](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

If the deletes are more complex, please provide more details; perhaps we can come up with another solution that deals with the question about index size.  Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Even if you cannot use partitions for purging, it *may* be useful to have partitions for `OPTIMIZE`.  Do *not* use `OPTIMIZE PARTITION`; it optimizes the entire table.  Instead, use `REORGANIZE PARTITION` if you see you need to shrink the index.

How big is the table?

How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

(6GB index does not seem that bad, especially since you have 32GB of RAM.)